# How to remove extra decimals from the column values if occurs in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to remove any 2nd decimal from the last of an row if it exists in a column.

**Input Data:**

```
column1

27.356.10
25689
2345.00
NaN
123.25.70
12.345.75.00
```

**Expected Output:**

```
column1

27356.10
25689
2345.00
NaN
12325.70
1234575.00
```

Code Used:

```
df['column1'] = df['column1'].replace('[^\d.]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
```

Above script removes special character but how 2nd or 3rd decimal from the last can be Removed if exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/DZqQHc/1):

```
df["column1"] = df["column1"].str.replace(r"(\.)(?=.*\.)", "", regex=True)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
      column1
0    27356.10
1       25689
2     2345.00
3         NaN
4    12325.70
5  1234575.00
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can choose not to use Regex:

```
df["column1"] = df["column1"].str.replace('.', '', df["column1"].count('.')-1)
```

I think this reads more intuitively -- replace `.` with `{empty}`  {count-of-periods-used}-1 times

```py
inputs = """27.356.10
25689
2345.00
NaN
123.25.70
12.345.75.00""".split('\n')

print(inputs)

for input in inputs:
    print(input.replace('.', '', input.count('.')-1))
```

```
['27.356.10', '25689', '2345.00', 'NaN', '123.25.70', '12.345.75.00']
27356.10
25689
2345.00
NaN
12325.70
1234575.00
```

Comment: which version of pandas? is `.count('.')` supposed to be `.str.count('.')`? this is an interesting idea but it doesn't work for me in `pd.__version__==1.2.3` even with `.str`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
l = df['column1'].str.rsplit('.',n=1,expand=True).fillna(0)
(l[0].str.replace('\.','') + '.' + l[1].astype(str)).astype(float)
```